# Show tooltip content when its hovers

Tags: css, jquery, tooltip

i am using this [Tooltips with Just CSS](http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-only-tooltips/) this is great. i am using this tool-tip to show big size images, but the problem is, this tool-tips makes my website slower because this used to load all the images when the website load... So, my question is how to Show tooltip content only when its hovers? So, the images will not load when the site will load.
I have followed this article [A little guide about jqueryui tooltip ajax callback](http://html5beta.com/jquery-2/a-little-guide-about-jqueryui-tooltip-ajax-callback/) and also this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvHT3/)

```
$('#tippy').tooltip({
content: '... waiting on ajax ...',
open: function(evt, ui) {
    var elem = $(this);
    $.ajax('/echo/html').always(function() {
        elem.tooltip('option', 'content', 'Ajax call complete');
     });
}
});
```

but can't understand how to use this with the tool-tip ... any idea?

Comment: It's hard to tell what images are being loaded, but one way you can reduce the amount of requests is to use a sprite for your images, possibly the ones being used in your tooltip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use JQuery to show/preload the image, you can save the image URL in the `data-*` atribute in tooltip first, and show the value as an `<img>` tag:

```
<a href="#" class="has-tooltip" data-image="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/food/1">link text</a>
```

The JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.has-tooltip').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.tooltip').html('<img src="'+$(this).data('image')+'" alt="loading...">').fadeIn();
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.tooltip').hide();
    }).append('<span class="tooltip"></span>');
});
```

And the CSS:

```
.has-tooltip {
  position:relative;
}

.has-tooltip .tooltip {
  display:none;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background-color:gray;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:10%;
  z-index:999;
}
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/tvHT3/62/

Comment: thanks man, its great.. one question, can i show a div tag instead of a simple image... thanks

Comment: Yes you can. Alternatively you can create your own tooltip markup and save some desired content in the HTML attribute >> http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/tvHT3/64/