# Using Image from Database as Tooltip

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, tooltip

I have a gridview.In this gridview there is a column that has hyperlink.I want to show an image as tooltip(on mouseover show the image).The path of the image is from the database("IMAGE" column) for every row.
my asp is:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >
    <Columns>           
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FULLNAME">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FULLNAME") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ID", "Players.aspx?ID={0}") %>' ToolTip='<%# "~/images/players/" + Eval("IMAGE") %>'  ID="HyperLink1"></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Is there any suggestion to make the tooltip image.
With this code it shows me the path of the image(photo shown below).

[image]

I want to show the image on mouseover.thanks

Comment: No no no. you cant show a image like that.. Better create a small div dynamically with image tag and set it and position it :)

Comment: How can show this div dynamically in every mouseover hyperlink?Any suggestion in c#?

Comment: Do you use jQuery in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the corect code. Is working perfect dynamically. Is from the post : [Show tooltip content when its hovers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139512/show-tooltip-content-when-its-hovers)
Thanks also to Murali.

```
         <asp:HyperLink CssClass="has-tooltip" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FULLNAME") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ID", "Players.aspx?ID={0}") %>' data-image='<%# "images/players/" + Eval("IMAGE") %>'  ID="HyperLink1"></asp:HyperLink>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.has-tooltip').hover(function () {
            $(this).find('.tooltip').html('<img src="' + $(this).data('image') + '" alt="loading...">').fadeIn();
        }, function () {
            $(this).find('.tooltip').hide();
        }).append('<span class="tooltip"></span>');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the help of jQuery, or write a plain javascript equivalent to the below code

```
 <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FULLNAME") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ID", "Players.aspx?ID={0}") %>' data-image-url='<%# "~/images/players/" + Eval("IMAGE") %>'  ID="HyperLink1"></asp:HyperLink>


$(document).ready(function(){

$('#<%= GridView1.ClientID%> a').mouseenter(function(){
   var imageUrl=$(this).data('image-url'); 
   var divContainer= $('<div><img src="+imageUrl+" /></div>');
    $(this).parent().append(divContainer);

});

$('#<%= GridView1.ClientID%> a').mouseleave(function(){

    $(this).next('div').hide()

});

});
```

Comment: I added this but is not working.I also add this            <div><asp:Image ID="Player" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "~/images/players/" + Eval("IMAGE") %>' /></div>

Comment: @Apollon, what error you are getting? Do you refer jQuery.js file in your .aspx page?

Comment: I refer the jquery-2.0.3.min.js in my masterpage.It doesn't give me error but in mouseover is not showing the images.

Comment: place a debugger/alert inside document.ready or inside `$('#GridView1 a')` and debug your code

Comment: @Apollon, Updated my answer for resolving dynamic id generation

Comment: @Apollon, you can add your tried version in your question or even you can add your answer as well  here.